# Git - Ahead of master because of online editing

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, commit

I'm using git as my VCS and I'm pushing my local rep to BitBucket.

I'm wokring on this project on my own, but I did the mistake that I edited one file (just changed few lines in readme.md) online from BitBucket's website.

Then I forgot to pull the changes to my local rep and I just kept adding more code, so now I can't push my last commit because I'm one commit (online readme.md change) ahead.  I'm afraid that if I would do `git pull` now I would erase all my new code.

Is there something I can do?
(I don't mind at all loosing all changes done in the commit done online, actually it would be great to just get rid of it.)

Comment: `git pull --rebase` will rebase your local version of the branch onto the origin (remote) version of the branch containing your readme changes

Comment: What is wrong with `git pull --rebase`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> actually it would be great to just get rid of it

Push has a `--force` option to do that, the history you've got as `master` doesn't include that commit so (a) git wants a little extra nudge and (b) since pushing syncs up the refs the upstream's `master` history wouldn't either.  Note that the commit actually still is in your upstream repo, it's just that master doesn't refer to it anymore. If nothing else in that repo refers to it either, git will eventually garbage-collect it there, but not for at least, by default, 30 days.

> I'm afraid that if I would do git pull now I would erase all my new code

That, it won't do.  Without the (recommended by one and all) `--rebase` option, the pull would do a recorded merge, with the two tips listed as parents of a merge commit.  For things with no administrative significance to anyone it's generally best to not bother recording merges.

If your history since the branch point is very much longer than the other branch's history (here, the other [repo's] branch has just the one divergent commit) it's worth considering whether to just fetch the upstream commits and cherry-pick them.

```
git fetch origin
git cherry-pick origin/master      # if you know for sure it's just the one commit
# or
git cherry-pick origin/master@{1}..origin/master    # to get however many new ones
```

and that will apply the changes in the picked commits on top of your history rather than applying the changes in your history on top of theirs.  The resulting content is the same either way, and your `master` references that directly.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to keep your online commit *and* push your local commit is to do:

```
git pull --rebase
```

That will replay your local commits on top of the updated `origin/master`.
Then you will be able to push normally: `git push`.